# hackers approach when DOM XSS contra reflected XSS?

Tags: javascript, dom, xss

Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong. I am somewhat confused by now. So I think my question will make more sense, if I explain my current understanding of the difference between DOM XSS and reflected XSS.

The difference in DOM XSS and reflected XSS is where the vulnerability lies in the application. In DOM XSS it lies in the HTML or script files that is sent to browser. 
Where reflected XSS targets vulnerabilities in the back-end, by manipulating the inside of API's or page requests to include scripts in the requested content.
Both work exclusively by including malicious content in a link.

---

As an attacker, how does the approach to abusing a vulnerable sites differ when looking for DOM XSS over reflected XSS exploits or vice versa? If such a difference even exists, and the two terms are only to distinguish between what part of an application got attacked?

Comment: [OWASP does classify them as different things](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Types_of_Cross-Site_Scripting#Reflected_XSS_.28AKA_Non-Persistent_or_Type_II.29). In particular, the difference is where the vulnerability is. A reflected XSS could be defeated on the server, a DOM XSS is a client-side vulnerability that server doesn't necessarily have a part in.

Comment: @VLAZ that confirmed my theory, thanks